# Firebase FCM notification LED lights

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using the Firebase HTTP API to send push notifications to my React Native Android app, and would like to have the LED light up when a notification is received. It doesn't seem like you can specify any kind of lights parameter in the message request, so how could I accomplish this?

Comment: You want the default FCM notification to light up the LEDs or your custom notification ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "custom notification" (it's not constructed on the device if that's what you mean), I just send notifications through the API.

Answer (score 0):

Apps using the FCM legacy HTTP API should consider migrating to the HTTP v1 API. The HTTP v1 API has these advantages over the legacy API.
While you use old HTTP protocol, you can't use vibration, LED and other feauters:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1?hl=en